# Alphanumeric Caesar's Cipher in Java

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to solve Caesar's Cipher in Java but there's a twist to it. The input string has alphanumeric values and I am unable to solve. Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
  String rotationalCipher(String input, int rotationFactor) {
    // Write your code here
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
      if(Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(i))) {
         char ch = (char)(((int)input.charAt(i) + rotationFactor - 97) % 26 + 97); 
      } else if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) {
          char ch = (char)(((int)input.charAt(i) + rotationFactor - 65) % 26 + 65); 
          sb.append(ch); 
      } else {
          char ch = (char)(((int)input.charAt(i) + rotationFactor - 48) % 10 + 48); 
          sb.append(ch); 
      }
    }
      return sb.toString();
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is evaluate each case using its ASCII values but I don't seem to get the desired output. Am I using ASCII wrong? Thanks for your help!

```
Sample input/output:
input = Zebra-493?
rotationFactor = 3
output = Cheud-726?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major problems.

- You did not update `StringBuilder` with an `append` for lowercase transitions.
- You need to handle digits specially using `isDigit` just like upper and lower case so that you can then ignore characters like - and ?

A couple of suggestions.

- just assign `ch` when you first enter the loop and then use it throughout the loop.  No need to keep typing in all the input stuff.
- only append `ch` to the StringBuilder once near the end when you exit the `if/else` blocks.
- Instead of numbers like 97 and 65 use 'a' and 'A'. Less likely to make mistakes that way.

Once you make those changes, your code works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for me-

```
  String rotationalCipher(String input, int rotationFactor) {
        // Write your code here
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char x = input.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLowerCase(x)) {
                char ch = (char) ((x + rotationFactor - 97) % 26 + 97);
                sb.append(ch);
            } else if (Character.isUpperCase(x)) {
                char ch = (char) ((x + rotationFactor - 65) % 26 + 65);
                sb.append(ch);
            } else if (Character.isDigit(x)) {
                char ch = (char) ((x + rotationFactor - 48) % 10 + 48);
                sb.append(ch);
            } else {
                sb.append(x);
            }

        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String rotationalCipher(String input, int rotationFactor) {
String output = "";
for(char a: input.toCharArray()){
   if(Character.isAlphabetic(a)){
     char startLetter = Character.isUpperCase(a) ? 'A' : 'a';
     output += (char) ((a- startLetter + rotationFactor) % 26 + startLetter);
   }
  else if(Character.isDigit(a)){
    output += (char) ((a + rotationFactor - 48) % 10 + 48);
   }
  else{
    output += a;
  }
}
return output;}
```

Comment: System.out.println(rotationalCipher(rotationalCipher("redzbmipor@gmail.com", 15), -15)) prodce bad results...o am I wrong wit decoding?